# Where is lbibitem used?

Tags: bibliographies

The class I was given to use has this line `\def\@lbibitem...`, and I could not find `\@lbibitem` anywhere else in the class, style file, etc.

Where is `\@lbibitem` actually used? How does a novice figure this out?

Comment: `@` is normally used in internal/helper commands of packages/classes, so you should not need to worry about it. All user commands should be listed and explained in the package/class documentation or, at the very least, in an example `.tex` file packaged with the class.

Comment: If the above is not the case, you probably have been given a poorly-designed or outdated class, and we'll need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) in order to help you out. By the way, forgot to say earlier: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks for your reply, but I'm actually trying to figure out how it works, which is why I asked. Finding the text "lbibitem" did not give any other result. How might I find the code that somehow adds an "l" in front of a name and calls the command?

Comment: `\@lbibitem` is originally defined in `latex.ltx` (the base LaTeX format) and used by _lots_ of other things. The class you're investigating is redefining it to influence all these other uses.

Comment: @user1537366 there is no generic code adding `l@` it is just the name of an internal macro, it could have been called `\zzzz` and work the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the latex format `\bibitem` is defined as

```
\def\bibitem{\@ifnextchar[\@lbibitem\@bibitem}


\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{\item[\@biblabel{#1}\hfill]\if@filesw
      {\let\protect\noexpand
       \immediate
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}


\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
       {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
```

so `\@lbibitem` is the internal macro that holds the real code of `\bibitem` in the case that an `[]` optional argument has been used.

Comment: Thank you. What the class did was to remove the [num] and have an out-dent. If I do not want to use the class, can I copy the code to my tex file, or is changing `\@lbibitem` a privilege of class files only? Maybe I should ask a new question about this.

Comment: @user1537366 you can put it in your own package or in your document preamble, in the latter case surround with `\makeatletter` .. `\makeatother` to access commands with `@` in their names.